# Where should Android applications call SQLite getWritableDatabase?

Tags: android, sqlite

The documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase%28%29 states:

> Database upgrade may take a long time,
>   you should not call this method
>   [getWritableDatabase] from the
>   application main thread, including
>   from ContentProvider.onCreate().

This begs the question: for best practice, where should getWritableDatabase be called from?

My feeling is that, perhaps, it should be called once upon application launch with a callback to mark the database as ready. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For small and agile databases I imagine this isn't much of an issue.

Otherwise, I'd use an always-wonderful `AsyncTask`, called from `onCreate`.

Answer (score 2):

It can be called from anywhere, but it should not be called from the UI thread because you don't know how long the process will take (especially with the different file systems in use).  Even if you know the database should be small, you don't know about the file system (can it perform more than one job at a time? are there are thousand other jobs waiting in line already?).  You can use an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread` to call getWriteableDatabase.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the intended use of the open helper framework, is to open the db on activity start, and close it when the Activity is destroyed.

In an AsyncTask from within onCreate()...

```
new StartupTask().execute();
```

The AsyncTask Thread.sleep() below is just to give enough time to show the dialog so that you can see it work.  Obviously take that out when you're done playing. ;)

```
private class StartupTask extends AsyncTask
{

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(final Object... objects)
    {
        openHelperRef.getWritableDatabase();
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                    MyActivity.this, "Title",
                    "Opening/Upgrading the database, please wait", true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object object)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(object);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

in onDestroy()...
    openHelper.close();